# Epsilon limit question proof verification/help (self study)

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show the following $\lim \frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}=0$.

So I have to show that $\forall \epsilon>0,  \exists N \in \mathbb{N} :\ when\ n \geq N$ it follows that $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$.

I choose $\epsilon= \frac{1}{5}$, thus $a_{n} \in ( \frac{1}{-5}, \frac{1}{5})$ when $n>3$ so I pick $N=4$.

So I have to show that $\forall \epsilon, \exists N : |\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}-0|< \epsilon$,

and then I am not sure how to continue. I have shown that for which $N$ will the sequence stay inside the epsilon interval. But turning it into a rigorous proof is a little bit hard to imagine, since this is my first proof with this technique.

Comment: I would use an upper bound first.  $2n^2/ (n^3 + 3) < 2n^2 / n^3$ ...

Comment: Also - you don't get to choose $\epsilon = 1/5$.  The proof has to work for every epsilon.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice:

$$\frac{2n^2}{n^3 + 3} < \frac{2n^2}{n^3} = \frac{2}{n}$$

Now, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $N$ so large that $2/N < \epsilon$, which is possible by the Archimedian property of the real numbers.

Then, if $N \leq n$, it follows that $1/n \leq 1/N$, and hence $$\frac{2n^2}{n^3 + 3} < \frac{2}{n} \leq \frac{2}{N} <\epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have proven that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N : \forall n \geq N: \frac{2n^2}{n^3 + 3} < \epsilon$$

which means that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n^2}{n^3 + 3} = 0$$

as desired.

---

Notice also that we could have immediately applied the squeeze/sandwich theorem. Indeed, we have:

$$0 \leq \frac{2n^2}{n^3 + 3} \leq \frac{2}{n}$$

and both the left and the right side go to $0$ if $n \to \infty$, meaning that the middle expression goes to $0$ as well.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't learned the Sandwich theorem. But your first proof looks like I gained some knowledge from that :). I just have one concern about the $N \in \mathbb{N}$ am I correct when I see this N as the value which assures that the sequence is inside the epsilon interval?

Comment: Yes, that $N$ works ! You don't have to find the smallest $N$ that does the job. Just finding one is enough, and the existence of such an $N is given by the Archimedian property of the real numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property

Answer (score 1):

In order to have rigor, we want to algebraically show that there exists an $N$ for each $\epsilon$. What you are doing right now looks a bit like trial and error, so we need to find some trick that works well. Here is a trick (which Jair Taylor also pointed out) that turns out to be very helpful here:
$$\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}<\frac{2n^2}{n^3}=\frac{2}{n}$$
Now if we pick an $\epsilon$, then we can find an $N$ which works, since we want $\frac{2}{N}<\epsilon$, we can rearrange as $N>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$, so just take $N=\lfloor\frac{2}{\epsilon}\rfloor + 1$, and we're done!

Answer (score 0):

$a_n:=\dfrac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \lt \dfrac{2n^2}{n^3} \lt \dfrac{2}{n}.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Let $M:= 2/\epsilon$.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0 > M$, $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

For $n \ge n_0$:

$|a_n-0| = \dfrac{2n^2}{n^3+3} \lt \dfrac{2}{n} \le \dfrac{2}{n_0} \le $

$\dfrac{2}{M} = \epsilon.$